Priority Queue inherited struct not in scope C++
i am implementing a custom priority queue witch inherits from a custom queue class. when i try to compile, i get an error saying the node struct is not in scope.
The error:
make
g++ -O2 src/test.cpp -o build/program.exe
In file included from src/test.cpp:7:
src/priority-queue.hpp: In member function ‘void DSLib::PriorityQueue<T, Compare>::EnQueue(T)’:
src/priority-queue.hpp:10:13: error: ‘Node’ was not declared in this scope
   10 |             Node* current = this->top;
      |             ^~~~
src/priority-queue.hpp:10:19: error: ‘current’ was not declared in this scope
   10 |             Node* current = this->top;
      |                   ^~~~~~~
src/priority-queue.hpp:14:19: error: ‘n’ was not declared in this scope
   14 |             Node* n = new Node(Value, current, (current != nullptr) ? current->prev : nullptr);
      |                   ^
src/priority-queue.hpp:14:27: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Node’
   14 |             Node* n = new Node(Value, current, (current != nullptr) ? current->prev : nullptr);
      |                           ^~~~
src/priority-queue.hpp:14:26: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘Node’
   14 |             Node* n = new Node(Value, current, (current != nullptr) ? current->prev : nullptr);
      |                          ^~~~~
      |                          ;
make: *** [Makefile:9: build/program.exe] Error 1

priority queue file:
#ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE
#define PRIORITY_QUEUE
#include "queue.hpp"

namespace DSLib {
    template<typename T, bool (*Compare)(T, T)>
    class PriorityQueue : public Queue<T> {
    public:
        void EnQueue(T Value) {
            Node* current = this->top;
            while (current != nullptr && Compare(Value, current->value)) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            Node* n = new Node(Value, current, (current != nullptr) ? current->prev : nullptr);
            if (current != nullptr) {
                if (current->prev != nullptr) {
                    current->prev->next = n;
                } else {
                    this->top = n;
                }
                current->prev = n;
            } else {
                this->bottom = n;
            }
            this->size++;
        }
    };
}
#endif

queue file:
#ifndef QUEUE_HPP 
#define QUEUE_HPP
#include <stdexcept>

namespace DSLib {
    template <typename T>
    class Queue {
    protected:
        struct Node {
        public:
            T value;
            Node* next;
            Node* prev;
            Node(T Value, Node* Next = nullptr, Node* Prev = nullptr) : value(Value), next(Next), prev(Prev) {}
        };

        int size;
        Node* top = nullptr;
        Node* bottom = nullptr;

    public:
        Queue() : size(0), top(nullptr), bottom(nullptr) {}

        ~Queue() {
            while (top != nullptr) {
                DeQueue();
            }
        }

        bool IsEmpty() {
            return size <= 0;
        }

        void EnQueue(T Value) {
            size++;
            Node* newNode = new Node(Value, nullptr, bottom);
            if (bottom != nullptr)
                bottom->next = newNode;
            bottom = newNode;
            if (top == nullptr)
                top = newNode;
        }

        T DeQueue() {
            if (IsEmpty()) {
                throw std::underflow_error("DeQueue Error: Queue Empty");
            }
            size--;
            T dequeuedValue = top->value;
            Node* oldTop = top;
            top = top->next;
            if (top != nullptr)
                top->prev = nullptr;
            else
                bottom = nullptr;
            delete oldTop;
            return dequeuedValue;
        }

        T Peek() {
            if (IsEmpty()) {
                throw std::underflow_error("Peek Error: Queue Empty");
            }
            return top->value;
        }

        void Sort(bool (*comparator)(const T&, const T&) = [](const T& a, const T& b) { return a < b; }) {
            Queue<T> sortedQueue;
            Queue<T> tempQueue;

            while (!IsEmpty()) {
                T minVal = Peek();
                while (!IsEmpty()) {
                    T val = DeQueue();
                    if (comparator(val, minVal)) {
                        minVal = val;
                    }
                    tempQueue.EnQueue(val);
                }
                bool minAdded = false;
                while (!tempQueue.IsEmpty()) {
                    T val = tempQueue.DeQueue();
                    if (val == minVal && !minAdded) {
                        sortedQueue.EnQueue(val);
                        minAdded = true;
                    } else {
                        EnQueue(val);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (!sortedQueue.IsEmpty()) {
                EnQueue(sortedQueue.DeQueue());
            }
        }

        class Iterator {
        private:
            Node* current;

        public:
            Iterator(Node* Start) : current(Start) {}

            bool operator!=(const Iterator& Other) const {
                return current != Other.current;
            }

            Iterator& operator++() {
                if (current) current = current->next;
                return *this;
            }

            T& operator*() const {
                return current->value;
            }
        };

        Iterator begin() const {
            return Iterator(top);
        }

        Iterator end() const {
            return Iterator(nullptr);
        }
    };
}
#endif


it still isnt working. i have tried Queue::Node, i have tried using Node = Queue::Node. i also tried putting a copy of the node struct inside PriorityQueue but that just gave me errors converting between Queue Node and PriorityQueue Node. it still doesnt work. am i missing something obvious?
Nevermind i fixed it. i just needed to do typename Queue::Node.

Make it Queue::Node or PriorityQueue::Node. To make it a dependent name for purposes of two-phase name lookup.

You could add using Node = Queue<T>::Node; in the definition of PriorityQueue to be able to use Node like you do now.
